# EF4 (CPT5) ForeignKeyAttribute in base class - Assert Failure entityType != null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Getting an error when trying to set a ForeignKeyAttribute in a base class

```
class User { }

abstract class FruitBase
{    
   [ForeignKey("CreateById")]
   public User CreateBy{ get; set; }

   public int CreateById{ get; set; }     
}

class Banana : FruitBase { }

class DataContext : DbContext
{    
   public DbSet<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }
}
```

If I move the FruitBase code into the banana, all is well, but I don't want to, as there will be many many fruit and I want to remain relatively DRY if I can

Is this a know issue that will be fixed by March?
Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: p.s. the error is a big assert failure dialog, I can upload an image if anyone wants to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem caused by the fact that in your DbContext you put `DbSet<Banana>` instead of `DbSet<FruitBase>`. The following object model works as expected:

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class FruitBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreateById { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreateById")]
    public User CreateBy { get; set; }
}

public class Banana : FruitBase { }

public class DataContext : DbContext
{        
    public DbSet<FruitBase> Fruits { get; set; }                
}
```

You have to be aware that by doing this, you are essentially creating a [***Polymorphic Association***](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx#PolymorphicAssociations) and as of CTP5, not all of the inheritance mapping strategies allow polymorphic association. Here it works fine because you've used [***Table per Hierarchy (TPH)***](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).

#### Update: Use [Table per Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) Strategy:

Polymorphic Associations work with TPT as well:

```
public class StackoverflowTestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FruitBase> Fruits { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Banana>().ToTable("Bananas");
    }         
}
```

Comment: Oh, if I added Apple I would be persisting it in the fruit table? What I want is a table for Bananas and a table for Apples and any other type... Is that possible?

Comment: Yes of course, then you are essentially looking for Table per Type (TPT) strategy. I've update my answer to show you how. I also encourage you to read my articles on Inheritance Strategies with Code First: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Comment: sorry Morteza, that's not what I'm after, it still creates a Fruits table, I want each fruit to map to a table and the FruitBase only supplies the common structure of theses tables. I am not after anything as complex as a Polymorphic Association here. perhaps my choice of Fruit as an example has thrown this into the equation but it was not intended. The base class is used to provide a common set of properties to be used on a number of conceptually unrelated objects

Comment: Ok what I am after is TPC, and, if I add a class of apples and a DbSet to match in the dataContext, remove the [ForeignKey("CreateById")] from the base, the table structure is as I want it, just no FK mapping and a [Type+Index] name on the FK column. When I pop it back in I get the Assert dialog.

Comment: Ok, you might want to particularly read the section under the title *Polymorphic Associations with TPC is Problematic* in the TPC article. Also read my answer to "Dimitris Foukas" on the comments for that article. In a nutshell, EF in general (and not only Code First) is not capable of handling your polymorphic association with TPC, period. You have to consider using TPT or giving up your polymorphic association (i.e. move it to the subclasses).

Comment: I suppose I was thinking of the base class here as a "template" for the sub classes and not actually oo polymorphic, i.e. I would never be doing anything where I would retrieve a list of fruit, I'd always be getting the Bananas or the Apples separately. I guess the way to do this is to implement an interface on each concrete type, as your answer to Dimitris suggests keeping the foreign key out of the inheritance hierarchy - thanks for your help on this

Comment: I exactly know your use case for TPC but unfortunately TPC mapping has a few bugs in CTP5 which prevent us to effectively use it for the top level of our class hierarchy. Also my answer to Dimitris does not really apply here since placing the foreign key on User table does not make sense in your scenario (I refer you to it so that you get a better idea of different scenarios on polymorphic associations with TPC).

Answer (score 0):

as discussed above, this is TPC ([Table per Concrete Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)), the answer/work around here is to take the ForeignKeyAttribute out of the base

```
class User{}

abstract class AuditObjectBase{ // was FruitBase

   // [ForeignKey("CreateById")]
   public abstract User CreateBy{ get; set; } // made abstract

   public int CreateById{ get; set; } // both get and set required public

}

class ItemOne : AuditObjectBase{ // Was Banana

   // added
   [ForeignKey("CreateById")]
   public override User CreateBy{ get; set; }
}

class ItemTwo : AuditObjectBase{ // Added

   [ForeignKey("CreateById")]
   public override User CreateBy{ get; set; }
}

class DataContext : DbContext{

   DbSet<ItemOne> ItemOnes{ get; set; }
   DbSet<ItemTwo> ItemTwos{ get; set; }
}
```

Not completely DRY but at least when you create an object which uses the AuditObjectBase it will force you to implement the Foreign Key property, some nice comments to remind you of the attribute and away you go

Basically it seams, attributes should be added to the class declared in the DbContext as an Entity, in this case has a DbSet property.